# Disable the SCSS sourcemap with PHPStorm 8.0.3 and Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby, phpstorm, file-watcher

I don't want a sourcemap to be generated when I use the SCSS filewatcher in PHPStorm 8.0.3.

Previously I used Ruby 2.0 and sent the enviroment variable `sourcemap` = `none`, but that doesn't work on my new development environment.

The only thing that's different between this PC and my old one is that I use Ruby 2.1, so maybe that's part of the reason?

I've tried `sourcemap` = `false` and `"sourcemap=none"` = `true`, but had no luck with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, of course, just a few minutes after I post the question I work out the answer.

You don't use environment variables at all, you add `--sourcemap=none` at the start of the `arguments` box (don't forget to put a space at the end to separate the new argument from all the ones there already).